# Class does not implement interface member when using generics

Tags: c#, generics, generic-interface

I have a generic interface defined as following:

```
interface INewRegionBoarding<T> where T: class
{
    bool Create(T objectName);
    bool ValidateData(T objectName);
}
```

Then, I have a class implementing it:

```
public class ESafeActionService<T>: INewRegionBoarding<T>
{
    public bool ValidateData(EsafeActons eSafe)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(eSafe.Corporation)) return false;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(eSafe.Region))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (eSafe.Region.Length != 2)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

       public bool Create(EsafeActons eSafe)
       {
           return eSafe.Create(eSafe.Corporation, eSafe.Region, eSafe.PortfolioName);
       }
    }
```

When building it, I have the following error:

`'ESafeActionService<EsafeActions>' does not implement interface member INewRegionBoarding<EsafeActions>.ValidateData(EsafeActions)'`

This is the `ESafeAction` class definition:

public class EsafeActons
{

```
private string corporation;
private string region;
private string portfolioName;

public EsafeActons(string corporation, string region, string portfolioName)
{
    this.corporation = corporation;
    this.region = region;
    this.portfolioName = portfolioName;
}


public string Corporation
{
    get { return this.corporation; }
    set { this.corporation = value; }
}

public string Region
{
    get{return this.corporation;}
    set { this.region = value; }
}

public string PortfolioName
{
    get { return this.corporation; }
    set { this.portfolioName = value; }
}

public bool Create(string corporation, string region, string portfolioName)
{
    //call stored proc
    return true;
}
```

}

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thank's

Comment: Which language? Please update question to add the tag of the language

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong

You're keeping the class generic but implementing the interface with a specific type.  Change your class definition to:

```
public class ESafeActionService: INewRegionBoarding<EsafeActons>
{
```